# Calloc - Memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management

Does calloc allocate return  contiguous memory location? If yes, what would it do if it is not available?

Comment: Do you mean a single call to calloc, or multiple calls to calloc, returning pointers to where the previously allocated block ended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does calloc allocate returns contiguous memory location?

Yes.<sup>1</sup>

> what would it do if it is not available?

Return `NULL`.

See section 7.20.3.1 of the C99 standard.

---

<sub>1. So far as the C program is concerned.  In a virtual memory system, the underlying physical memory used may not be contiguous.</sub>

Comment: So , all the memory blkocks returned by calloc are stored contiguously?

Comment: @zahreelay: If the memory in each allocation wasn't contiguous, it wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: No, if you mean different calls to calloc, that is not guaranteed.

Comment: @zahreelay: yes from the point of view of the process. Not necessarily from the point of view of the hardware.

Comment: @Mat: I was gonna say something similar :)  A RAM module may become full and the next module may need to be used - they are still considered contiguous by the controller though, despite the differences in their addresses.

Comment: @vol7ron: with virtual memory, it could be _much_ more scattered than that. A four-pages-big virtual mapping could be scattered on four different numa nodes that might not even be in the same "box" (while sill appearing contiguous to the process).

Comment: @Mat: yes, and then there's the fact that memory blocks go bad and also have to be discarded

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the C standard guarantees that the pointer returned by calloc is either NULL or points to a block of contiguous memory.